# Download functionality in Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

I am new to Tornado web framework. Can any one tell me how to download the file through web browser using tornado framework.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tornado comes with both a synchronous and asynchronous HTTP client. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#http-client-interfaces).

Here's a synchronous example taken from the page linked above:

```
from tornado import httpclient
http_client = httpclient.HTTPClient()
try:
    response = http_client.fetch(url)
    print(response.body)
except httpclient.HTTPError as e:
    print("Error:", e)
http_client.close()
```

If you want to save the resulting output to disk then instead of printing the data, write it out to a file. Note that even in Python 3, Tornado returns response bodies as strings:

```
with open(output_file_name) as f:
    f.write(response.body)
```

Of course, if the response data is very large, you'll want to download the file in chunks and write to disk on-the-fly ([see here](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2011/10/tornado-httpclient-chunked-downloads.html)).

Finally, if you're not constrained to Tornado for some reason, I would highly recommend the `requests` library (or `grequests` for asynchronous calls).

EDIT:
To serve a static file as a download, do something like this in your handler's `get`:

```
def get(self):
    file_name = 'file.ext'
    buf_size = 4096
    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + file_name)
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(buf_size)
            if not data:
                break
            self.write(data)
    self.finish()
```

You may or may not have byte/string issues in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But my question is that for example if i am an end user. I have visited example.com site , In there if I click the download button then the file need to download in the respective browser.

Comment: Ah, I had wondered why you said "through a web browser," but dismissed it.